# LoRaWAN Multicast setup

Tags: lorawan

I'm trying to create a LoRaWAN network with multicast using TTN. I have followed several videos and accessed anything I could find, but fundamentally it seems I cannot understand concept behind the keys.

My point of reference is https://lora-alliance.org/resource_hub/lorawan-remote-multicast-setup-specification-v1-0-0/
and video: https://youtu.be/qpnjOjHTCDc

I have successfully send Payloads on fport 200 and received the correct responses from my device, but when I schedule a downlink message to the MC group on say fport 1, nothing is received at the device.
My end device is an STM32WL nucleo.

Info on my device after boot:

###### AppKey:      2B:7E:15:16:28:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:CF:4F:3C

###### NwkKey:      2B:7E:15:16:28:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:CF:4F:3C

###### AppSKey:     2B:7E:15:16:28:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:CF:4F:3C

###### NwkSKey:     2B:7E:15:16:28:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:CF:4F:3C

###### DevEUI:      00:80:E1:15:05:00:5D:C7

###### AppEUI:      01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01

###### DevAddr:     05:00:5D:C7

After OTAA JOIN
+EVT:JOINED

###### MCRootKey:   7D:F7:6B:0C:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:47:B9:1B:54:6F

###### MCKEKey:     8C:B8:66:5E:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:E4:8A:19:27:7C

###### AppSKey:     D0:B5:EE:1D:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:CF:1B:8B:45:1E

###### NwkSKey:     0F:83:21:17:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:DE:E5:C9:17:79

###### DBIntKey:    7A:C4:7C:65:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:35:19:F8:9C:8E

###### DevEUI:      00:80:E1:15:05:00:5D:C7

###### AppEUI:      01:01:01:01:01:01:01:01

###### DevAddr:     26:0C:92:DF

After sending McGroupSetupReq (0x02)

###### ID          : 0

###### McAddr      : 260CA2A7

###### McKey       : C0-27-FE-A2-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-51-98-A3-8B

###### McFCountMin : 0

###### McFCountMax : 10

###### SessionTime : 2541666257

###### SessionTimeT: 32768 s

###### Rx Freq     : 869525000

###### Rx DR       : DR_3

My Setup on TTN (as a multicast device/group)
[image: TTN Setup]

Question1: Both references above refer to "McKey_encrypted" ... where is this key derived from? and what method can be used to derive MCRootKey and McKEKey?

Question1.1: Why do these already exist on my end device?

Question2: What keys should be taken from the multicast device/group created on TTN and put on the device

Question3: What keys should be taken from the device and put on the multicast device/group on TTN

Question4: What keys should be common on devices that will be part of the multicast?

Question5: Which is the key that should be included in the McGroupSetupReq command (if you can use any keys references above)